# Mobile Push Logs in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, mobilepush

Is there a way I can query the push messages sent through MC for a particular subscriber (i.e. via Data Views?)

If not, how else have people something like this, I'd want to stay away from using reports as I want to be able to query and segment against the data using Data Extensions.

Comment: So far only reports, extracted then imported have been possible despite search and also conversations with Salesforce. Will update if that changes as those are still ongoinh

Comment: Is it possible to automate that report and get the CSV file to the SFTP site?